# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf: combine filtering and pagination for list

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Good evening all,

I'm learning Thymeleaf and web applications in general right now, and for starters, I'm trying to implement a web service with a page where you can view all registered users and filter them.

Since I want some pagination, I have two forms on this page:

- a group of buttons linking to the first, previous, next, and last page
- a form with various options for filtering, e.g. "username contains" or "min / max age"

My controller looks like this:

```
    @RequestMapping("/users/all")
    String showSearchPage(@RequestParam(value="page", required=false, defaultValue = "0") int page,
                          @CurrentSecurityContext(expression="authentication?.name") String username,
                          Model model) {
        Page<User> userPage = userService.filterUsers(username, "", 0, 100, PageRequest.of(page, 10));
        model.addAttribute("userPage", userPage);
        model.addAttribute("pageNr", page);

        return "users.html";
    }
```

As you can see, I only implemented the buttons yet and always filter for some default values. (The `username` parameter makes sure that the currently logged in user isn't finding themself in the list.) My button form looks like that:

```
<form class="button" th:action="@{/users/all}" method="POST">
    <button th:disabled="${pageNr == 0}" type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            name="page" th:value="0"><<</button>
    <button th:disabled="${pageNr == 0}" type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            name="page" th:value="${pageNr - 1}"><</button>
    <button th:disabled="${pageNr == userPage.getTotalPages - 1}" type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            name="page" th:value="${pageNr + 1}">></button>
    <button th:disabled="${pageNr == userPage.getTotalPages - 1}" type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            name="page" th:value="${userPage.getTotalPages - 1}">>></button>
</form>
```

So I'm using the request parameter `page` to only show the requested page.

Now that I'm about to implement the filtering, my first approach would be adding the form to my HTML, and adding some `@ModelAttribute FilterForm filterForm` to my controller to be able to get the submitted filter values and use them to retrieve the filtered user list. However, when thinking about it, I found the problem that both forms would only submit their own content, and the controller would only get one of both. Therefore, after filtering users, I would inadvertedly revert back to the full user list when changing pages.

What would be the best approach here to make sure that both functions, filtering and pagination, work together properly?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with HTTP GET method instead of POST. Why so? Reading users is an idempotent and safe operation. The applied filter and page number can be easily bookmarked in that case.
For filters, you can just add more params. Nothing bad about that.
Make it a bit more RESTful. "/users/all" is unnecessary. "/users" should be enough.

```
@GetMapping("/users")
String showSearchPage(@RequestParam(value="page", required=false, defaultValue = "0") int page, 
                      @RequestParam("minAge") Optional<Integer> minAge, 
                      @RequestParam("maxAge") Optional<Integer> maxAge,
                      @CurrentSecurityContext(expression="authentication?.name") String username,
                      Model model) {
    // Apply filters too...
    Page<User> userPage = userService.filterUsers(username, "", 0, 100, PageRequest.of(page, 10));
    model.addAttribute("userPage", userPage);
    model.addAttribute("pageNr", page);
    model.addAttribute("nextPage", getPageWithFilterUrl(page + 1, minAge, maxAge));
    model.addAttribute("previousPage", getPageWithFilterUrl(page - 1, minAge, maxAge));
    return "users.html";
}
```

To preserve filter while moving back and forth:

```
private String getPageWithFilterUrl(int page, Optional<Integer> minAge, Optional<Integer> maxAge) {
    String defaultNextPageUrl = "/users?page=" + page;
    String withMinAge = minAge.map(ma -> defaultNextPageUrl + "&minAge=" + ma).orElse(defaultNextPageUrl);
    String withMaxAge = maxAge.map(ma -> withMinAge + "&maxAge=" + ma).orElse(withMinAge);
    return withMaxAge;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on the optimal way to bookmark those parameters?

Comment: @Noel93 I'm talking about browser URL bookmarking. If the params are in the URL, then the URL can be bookmarked containing filter and page.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how to solve my problem. Let's say I look at page 0, then enter some filters and everything's fine, however when I then click the "next page" button, we will access /users?page=1 and the filters will be lost. My controller could add the filter parameters to the model so that I can access them with Thymeleaf, but can a button send back more than one name/value pair?

Comment: @Noel93 That's a good point actually. You could even build your "next", "previous" URLs (based on the presence of params) in Java code and set them in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is not given here yet. I have the same problem now. I am trying in my project with redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("searchProductItemDTO", searchProductItemDTO);
But the problem comes when clicking on the Next/Previous buttons - clicking them does not take into account the search criteria.

Comment: And does that work? Or are you only saying "me too"?

Comment: Well, I just added the full answer in a new post comment

Comment: Why? Do you think that this post is a good one on its own and that the new one is also a good one on its own? Would you not like to instead [edit] this one, in order to have the best possible one? I recommend to delete the other one. You could make this one to be according to [answer], for the best chances of being perceived as helpful and clear. And why do you think that by using the "Post Your Answer" button you are creating a comment? You can only comment your own posts, as you did here, but you cannot otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my total solution:

1) Pay attention here to the JpaSpecificationExecutor<ItemEntity>
@Repository
public interface AllItemsRepository   extends 
PagingAndSortingRepository<ItemEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ItemEntity>{ 
}

2) Pay attention here to the CriteriaBuilder
public class ProductItemSpecification implements Specification<ItemEntity> {
    private final SearchProductItemDTO searchProductItemDTO;
    private final String type;

    public ProductItemSpecification(SearchProductItemDTO searchProductItemDTO, String type) {
        this.searchProductItemDTO = searchProductItemDTO;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ItemEntity> root,
                                 CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                                 CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        Predicate predicate = cb.conjunction();

        predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.equal(root.get("type"), type));

        if (searchProductItemDTO.getModel() != null && !searchProductItemDTO.getModel().isBlank()) {
            Path<Object> model = root.get("model");
            predicate.getExpressions().add(
                    //!!!!! when we have two relationally connected tables
//                    cb.and(cb.equal(root.join("model").get("name"), searchProductItemDTO.getModel()));

                    //when all fields are from the same table ItemEntity:::: the like works case insensitive
   cb.and(cb.like(root.get("model").as(String.class), "%" + searchProductItemDTO.getModel() + "%"))
            );
        }

        if (searchProductItemDTO.getMinPrice() != null) {
            predicate.getExpressions().add(
                    cb.and(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("sellingPrice"),
                            searchProductItemDTO.getMinPrice()))
            );
        }

        if (searchProductItemDTO.getMaxPrice() != null) {
            predicate.getExpressions().add(
                    cb.and(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("sellingPrice"),
                            searchProductItemDTO.getMaxPrice()))
            );
        }

        return predicate;
    }
}


3) Pay attention here to the this.allItemsRepository.findAll default usage
//Complicated use
public Page<ComputerViewGeneralModel> getAllComputersPageableAndSearched(
        Pageable pageable, SearchProductItemDTO searchProductItemDTO, String type) {

    Page<ComputerViewGeneralModel> allComputers = this.allItemsRepository
            .findAll(new ProductItemSpecification(searchProductItemDTO, type), pageable)
            .map(comp -> this.structMapper
                    .computerEntityToComputerSalesViewGeneralModel((ComputerEntity) comp));

    return allComputers;
}


4) Pay attention here to the redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/items/all")
public class ViewItemsController {
    private final ComputerService computerService;

@GetMapping("/computer")
public String viewAllComputers(Model model,
                               @Valid SearchProductItemDTO searchProductItemDTO,
                               @PageableDefault(page = 0,
                                       size = 3,
                                       sort = "sellingPrice",
                                       direction = Sort.Direction.ASC) Pageable pageable,
                               RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    if (!model.containsAttribute("searchProductItemDTO")) {
        model.addAttribute("searchProductItemDTO", searchProductItemDTO);
    }

    Page<ComputerViewGeneralModel> computers = this.computerService
            .getAllComputersPageableAndSearched(pageable, searchProductItemDTO, "computer");
    model.addAttribute("computers", computers);

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("searchProductItemDTO", searchProductItemDTO);

    return "/viewItems/all-computers";
}

5) Pay attention here to all the search params that we add in the html file, in the 4 sections where pagination navigation
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="text-center text-white">Search for offers</h2>
            <form
                    th:method="GET"
                    th:action="@{/items/all/computer}"
                    th:object="${searchProductItemDTO}"
                    class="form-inline"
                    style="justify-content: center; margin-top: 50px;"
            >
                <div style="position: relative">
                    <input
                            th:field="*{model}"
                            th:errorclass="is-invalid"
                            class="form-control mr-sm-2"
                            style="width: 280px;"
                            type="search"
                            placeholder="Model name case Insensitive..."
                            aria-label="Search"
                            id="model"
                    />
                    <input
                            th:field="*{minPrice}"
                            th:errorclass="is-invalid"
                            class="form-control mr-sm-2"
                            style="width: 280px;"
                            type="search"
                            placeholder="Min price..."
                            aria-label="Search"
                            id="minPrice"
                    />
                    <input
                            th:field="*{maxPrice}"
                            th:errorclass="is-invalid"
                            class="form-control mr-sm-2"
                            style="width: 280px;"
                            type="search"
                            placeholder="Max price..."
                            aria-label="Search"
                            id="maxPrice"
                    />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <h2 class="text-center text-white mt-5 greybg" th:text="#{view_all_computers}">.........All
            Computers.......</h2>
        <div class="offers row mx-auto d-flex flex-row justify-content-center .row-cols-auto">
            <div
                    th:each="c : ${computers}" th:object="${c}"
                    class="offer card col-sm-2 col-md-3  col-lg-3 m-2 p-0">

                <div class="card-img-top-wrapper" style="height: 20rem">
                    <img
                            class="card-img-top"
                            alt="Computer image"
                            th:src="*{photoUrl}">
                </div>

                <div class="card-body pb-1">
                    <h5 class="card-title"
                        th:text="' Model: ' + *{model}">
                        Model name</h5>
                </div>

                <ul class="offer-details list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="card-text"><span th:text="'* ' + *{processor}">Processor</span></div>
                        <div class="card-text"><span th:text="'* ' + *{videoCard}">Video card</span></div>
                        <div class="card-text"><span th:text="'* ' + *{ram}">Ram</span></div>
                        <div class="card-text"><span th:text="'* ' + *{disk}">Disk</span></div>
                        <div th:if="*{!ssd.isBlank()}" class="card-text"><span th:text="'* ' + *{ssd}">SSD</span></div>
                        <div th:if="*{!moreInfo.isBlank()}" class="card-text"><span th:text="'* ' + *{moreInfo}">More info</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text"><span th:text="'We sell at: ' + *{sellingPrice} + ' лв'"
                                                     style="font-weight: bold">Selling price</span></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="btn btn-link"
                           th:href="@{/items/all/computer/details/{id} (id=*{itemId})}">Details</a>

                        <th:block sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN') || hasRole('EMPLOYEE_PURCHASES')">
                            <a class="btn btn-link alert-danger"
                               th:href="@{/pages/purchases/computers/{id}/edit (id=*{itemId})}">Update</a>

                            <form th:action="@{/pages/purchases/computers/delete/{id} (id=*{itemId})}"
                                  th:method="delete">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-link alert-danger" value="Delete"></input>
                            </form>
                        </th:block>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid row justify-content-center">
            <nav>
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item" th:classappend="${computers.isFirst()} ? 'disabled' : ''">
                        <a th:unless="${computers.isFirst()}"
                           class="page-link"
                           th:href="@{/items/all/computer(size=${computers.getSize()},page=0,model=${searchProductItemDTO.getModel()}, minPrice=${searchProductItemDTO.getMinPrice()},maxPrice=${searchProductItemDTO.getMaxPrice()})}">First</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <nav>
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item" th:classappend="${computers.hasPrevious() ? '' : 'disabled'}">
                        <a th:if="${computers.hasPrevious()}"
                           class="page-link"
                           th:href="@{/items/all/computer(size=${computers.getSize()},page=${computers.getNumber() - 1},model=${searchProductItemDTO.getModel()}, minPrice=${searchProductItemDTO.getMinPrice()},maxPrice=${searchProductItemDTO.getMaxPrice()})}">Previous</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <nav>
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item" th:classappend="${computers.hasNext() ? '' : 'disabled'}">
                        <a th:if="${computers.hasNext()}"
                           class="page-link"
                           th:href="@{/items/all/computer(size=${computers.getSize()},page=${computers.getNumber() + 1},model=${searchProductItemDTO.getModel()}, minPrice=${searchProductItemDTO.getMinPrice()},maxPrice=${searchProductItemDTO.getMaxPrice()})}">Next</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <nav>
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item" th:classappend="${computers.isLast()} ? 'disabled' : ''">
                        <a th:unless="${computers.isLast()}"
                           class="page-link"
                           th:href="@{/items/all/computer(size=${computers.getSize()},page=${computers.getTotalPages()-1},model=${searchProductItemDTO.getModel()},minPrice=${searchProductItemDTO.getMinPrice()},maxPrice=${searchProductItemDTO.getMaxPrice()})}">Last</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>`enter code here`
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.